# Chrome Takes Forever to Connect Upon Waking Up From Sleep

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, sleep

I have a laptop that is exhibiting a weird problem. Upon waking up from sleep chrome takes FOREVER to allow me to reload pages. It does not display a "no internet connection" screen, it doesnt show any obvious errors, it's not frozen, it just sits there and reloads whatever page I refresh/visit indefinitely. It will take sometimes 2-3 minutes from boot for chrome to "wake up" and start working again. This compares to other applications I use like Slack, which come up within 10 seconds or so from regaining my connection to the internet.

I've deleted any obvious extensions, and trying this in incognito doesn't fix it etiher. It is *very* strange. So strange in fact, I don't even know what to Google for.

Chrome: `Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Windows: `Windows 10 Pro 1709 Build 16299.248`

Here's a list of extensions I currently have running:

- Lastpass
- NoScript
- AdNauseum
- DuckDuckGo
- HTTPS Everywhere
- React

Additionally, I have tested this problem in Microsoft Edge and Edge works immediately upon waking up. This is certainly isolated to Chrome.

I am running ESET Internet Security, but if that was a problem I'd expect it to be a problem everywhere. Has anyone encountered this before and been able to fix it?

**Things I have Tried**

- Deleting extensions - No Fix
- Turning off ESET Internet Security - No Fix
- Using a different browser (this doesn't occur on any other browser)
- Waking the computer up from sleep and trying a *new* Chrome browser window - No Fix

Comment: Does this happen with another browser?  If it does, than you know its most likely an OS issue, not Chrome.

Comment: @Keltari Microsoft Edge works just fine immediately upon waking up. This is definitely a Chrome issue. I'll add that test to the topic.

Comment: Does Chrome do this if it is left open during standby/resume? Or if you close and reopen Chrome after resume? Or both?

Comment: @Appleoddity Both.

Comment: What antivirus software do you have?

Comment: @Appleoddity ESET Internet Security, which includes ESET NOD32

Comment: Ok. I always suspect internet security products in this situation because they are predominantly the cause of issues like this. You should try completely disabling the product, or if the problem still persists, I would try uninstalling it completely, at least temporarily. I know it’s inconvenient, but these products are so notorious for strange connectivity issues like this you have to try.

Comment: @Appleoddity Disability Firewall/Antivirus/Antispyware and sleeping/waking up the computer did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be caused by Windows settings for auto-detect of proxy settings.  With Chrome `Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)` I have resolved this as follows:

Windows 7:
Open Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center
Open Internet Options (lower left)
Select Connections, LAN Settings and clear the checkbox on "Automatically detect settings"

Windows 10: 
Windows Settings - Network & Internet - Proxy. Turn of "Automatically Detect Settings"

I assume the long delay is somehow due to each Chrome tab separately trying to detect settings.  The issue appears to existed for a few years, if you search for "chrome slow after resume from hibernate".